# How to use a local file for SAM AWS::Serverless::HttpApi

Tags: openapi, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am making a super simple SAM template. I took an implicit api and am attempting to move it to an explicit with an `openapi.yaml` file.

When I put the content of the file in the `DefinitionBody` and run `sam validate` the output is all good. So I know that my openapi format is proper.

I take that same content for openapi and put it in the yaml file and then reference it like this:

```
  TestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: './openapi.yaml'
```

Based on the documentation:

> DefinitionUri:
> The Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) URI, local file path, or location object of the the OpenAPI definition that defines the HTTP API.

Now when I run `sam validate` I get:

> E0001 Error transforming template: Resource with id [TestApi] is invalid. 'DefinitionUri' is not a valid S3 Uri of the form 's3://bucket/key' with optional versionId query parameter.

This could be a miss on my part for what the `sam cli` is supposed to do. Still trying to understand this tooling. I thought I would want to run the `sam validate` step before doing any build/package to make sure the format is correct.

Should I be able to validate a sam template with an external local openapi file and is this the correct format to reference a file?